# How to query XML nodes based on the value of the attribute of its parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an XML which looks something like this:

```
<Library>
<Author Name = "JRR Tolkien">
<Book Title = "Lord Of the Rings" />
<Book Title = "The Hobbit" />
</Author>
<Author Name = "JK Rowling">
<Book Title = "Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone" />
<Book Title = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban" />
</Author>
</Library>
```

What is the XPath to select all the "Book" nodes whose parent "Author" node has the value "JK Rowling"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is properly more most intuitive and strict which selects all the books which have a `Author` which `Name` attribute is `'JK Rowling'` as a parent. And the `Author` must also have the `Library` as a parent.

```
/Library/Author[@Name='JK Rowling']/Book
```

Comment: Yes, the 2nd option is much clearer. I was about to post something similar, but you edited your answer before ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you both. So I deleted the first because it did not do any good.